# When I select the value from the combo box, related value should appear in the text box

Tags: vb6

When I select the value from the combo box, related value should appear in the text box

ComboBox code.

```
cmd.CommandText = "select distinct PERSONID from T_PERSON"
    Set rs = cmd.Execute
    While Not rs.EOF
        If Not IsNull(rs("PersonID")) Then
            txtno.AddItem rs("PersonID")
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend
```

In comboBox list of ID is displaying, when I select the particular person id, Name should display in text box related to the personid

Text Box

```
cmd.CommandText = "select distinct Name from T_Person where personid = '" & txtno & " '"
    Set rs = cmd.Execute

    While Not rs.EOF
       If Not IsNull(rs("Name")) Then
    txtName.Text = rs("Name")
           rs.MoveNext
        End If
    Wend
```

I put the above code in Form_Load Event, Nothing displaying in Text Box.

What wrong in my code.

Need VB6 code Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want the 2nd block of code in the the click event for the combobox.

**Edit**

There looks like another couple of issues in your code at this line:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select distinct Name from T_Person where personid = '" & txtno & " '"
```

2 Issues:

You are passing in the control itself as the person ID, not the selected value.

You have an extra space in your query after the person ID

You should change that line to be:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select distinct Name from T_Person where personid = '" & txtno.SelectedItem.Text & "'"
```

Comment: This reply is correct the code needs to be in the Click event not the form load event.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have the combobox display the name and hold the personID as it's item data?

```
cmd.CommandText = "select distinct PERSONID, Name from T_PERSON WHERE PersonID IS NOT NULL"
Set rs = cmd.Execute
While Not rs.EOF
     combo.AddItem rs("Name").value
     combo.ItemData(combo.NewIndex) = rs("PERSONID").value
     rs.MoveNext
Wend
```

Then, if you need the PersonID for the selected name you can just grab combo.ItemData(combo.ListIndex).